# Open ball does not have fixed point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

How we can prove that the open ball in $R^n$ does not have fixed point property (by algebraic topology concepts)?
I know $D^n$ -closed ball in $R^n$- has fixed point property by Brouwer's theorem, but can't see how to find the function which has not a fixed point in the aforementioned case.

Would be grateful for your help.

Comment: How about the one-dimensional case? E.g. a fixed-point-free map from $(0,1)$ into itself?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R^n}$, $x \to \dfrac{x-1}{2}$. Basically a translation followed by a contraction.

Comment: @Soumya :  The map you've defined has a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But it doesn't have a fixed point in $D^n$, which is what Brouwer would've promised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that any non-empty, non-compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ lacks the fixed point property](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792325/show-that-any-non-empty-non-compact-convex-subset-of-mathbbrn-lacks-the-f)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb R^n$ does not have fixed point property (think of translation). The open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, so it does not have fixed point property either.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the open ball of radius $\frac 1 2$ around $(\frac 1 2, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$, and the function $f$ which takes the $(n-1)$-dimensional cross-section at first coordinate $x$ to that of first coordinate $x^2$.

Comment: Excuse me I can't understand the $(n-1)$-dimensional cross-section; could you a little more explain? Thanks.